# How does the wired Tado smart thermostat operate without a neutral connection?

Tags: thermostat

I’ve been studying the wiring diagrams for the Tado smart thermostat and noticed that it only uses a live ‘common’ and a switched live to operate.

Given the smart thermostat has electronics which are, for want of a better term ‘always on’ and connected to home Wi-Fi etc, how can this be the case without a neutral wire?

I assumed there would be a built-in battery, but I see no mention of how to replace this on their site.

Can anyone explain how this might work?

[Tado wired thermostat installation manual](https://www.tado.com/start/manuals/st/Wired%20Smart%20Thermostat%20Manual.pdf)

Comment: what do you mean by `switched live`? ... does the thermostat replace a simple termostatically operated mechanical switch?

Comment: Yes, live in, switched live out. I’ll update the question with a link to the manual.

Comment: think about this ... the switched live circuit probably allows small current to flow without activating the furnace

Comment: OK, this is where my knowledge falls down. How is a neutral not required? I was always under the impression a neutral was required to power something off an AC circuit.

Comment: the power is provided by the small leakage current that flows when the furnace is not active

Comment: Ah ok, I think you might be misunderstanding here. There is a constant 240v going into the thermostat regardless. When the thermostat activates, it closes the circuit, activating the boiler. Having read up on this I’m starting to see that a neutral is not necessarily required on an AC powered device but it would be nice to get some clarification.

Comment: it is you that does not understand ... the thermostat allows leakage current to pass ... that current is used by the thermostat to power itself .... the current is not enough to activate the boiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user manual says that the Wired Smart Thermostat uses AAA batteries.

You are reading the installation manual which does not mention this.

Comment: With a link to the user manual, this would be a perfect answer to the question ;)

Comment: Well you're quite right, received the stat this week and low and behold... AAA batteries. I guess the same question applies for a LightwaveRF smart lightswitch I have but I'll have that for another day. Who knows.. that could have concealed batteries!

Answer (score 0):

This is my guess:

The “switched live” goes to a relay, which is connected to neutral.  So the thermostat takes the AC power in and sends it to the “switched live” wire to switch the relay ON.

So if the thermostat wants to get a little power for itself, it can connect AC power to “switched live” but restrict the current so the relay doesn’t actually switch ON. Or it can do it at a frequency much higher than the relay’s max switching frequency.  Either way, the thermostat gains access to neutral through the relay and is able to complete the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the heat request relay is not actuated, the open contact provide voltage and are the power supply for the thermostat. As long as you limit your current consumption to below the heaters activation threshold, you're ok!

Inside the Tado is a supercapacitor that is used to store some energy to remain operational during heating, since then the relay closes you lose the supply.
And since heating should be much less time than non-heating, you can power the unit this way.

It using a very low power sub-Ghz wireless link and a low power MSP430 microcontroller make this possible.

However if possible, avoid using the relays. Today there is OpenTherm and the Tado is able to use this. This is a data over low voltage power communication providing both control, diagnostics and power. See if your

[Here](https://0xfred.wordpress.com/2016/07/30/hacking-the-tado-part-3-thermostat/) are some images of the inside.